# how can I read a binary file using VBA?

Tags: vba, binary

I have a binary file that resulted from a program written in Compaq Visual Fortran.
How can I read specific lines and save them in an Excel sheet?

Comment: How does a binary file have "lines"?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to read the entire file into one big array, you can use the following code:

```
Dim byteArr() As Byte
Dim fileInt As Integer: fileInt = FreeFile
Open "C:\path\to\my\file.ext" For Binary Access Read As #fileInt
ReDim byteArr(0 To LOF(fileInt) - 1)
Get #fileInt, , byteArr
Close #fileInt
```

The result is identical to the answer by Todd Owen, but achieved without the use of external libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is using ADODB.Stream:

```
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = 1  ' adTypeBinary
    .LoadFromFile file.Path
    bytes = .Read
    .Close
End With
```

(Sorry, I'm not actually sure what library it's in, which is why this sample code uses CreateObject and the literal value 1 instead of the named constant adTypeBinary!)

Comment: The library is Microsoft Active Data Object.

Comment: why using an external library for such a trivial and built-in task?

Comment: Refrence Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library

Comment: Dim bytes As Variant

Answer (score 7):

You have to open it using "Binary Access".

See http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=430424

```
Sub Temp()
    Dim intFileNum%, bytTemp As Byte, intCellRow%
    intFileNum = FreeFile
    intCellRow = 0
    Open "C:\temp.bin" For Binary Access Read As intFileNum
    Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
        intCellRow = intCellRow + 1
        Get intFileNum, , bytTemp
        Cells(intCellRow, 1) = bytTemp
    Loop
    Close intFileNum
End Sub
```