# VBA - Read 15 MB binary file to var

Tags: excel, vba, binaryfiles

Is it possible in Excel VBA to read a binary file to a variable?

A function similar to:

```
function bin2var(filename as String) As XXXX
```

And also, is it possible to do the reverse operation?

```
function var2bin(filename as String,data as XXXX)
```

Comment: What makes you think it isn't possible..? What have you tried so far that doesn't work..?

Comment: It's totally possible. But what kind of variable do you want? A Byte array, or a String?

Comment: @Sean This:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660312/how-can-i-read-a-binary-file-using-vba but it's not exactaly what I need...

Comment: @Diga: You accepted my answer very fast. Make sure you copied the version with the #1/#f fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Function bin2var(filename As String) As String
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Binary Access Read Lock Write As #f
        bin2var = Space(FileLen(filename))
        Get #f, , bin2var
    Close #f
End Function

Sub var2bin(filename As String, data As String)
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Output Access Write Lock Write As #f
        Print #f, data;
    Close #f
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting Boann's code as it writes a new line (2 byte) at the end of the output file.

```
Function bin2var(filename As String) As String
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Binary Access Read Lock Write As #f
        bin2var = Space(FileLen(filename))
        Get #f, , bin2var
    Close #f End Function

Sub var2bin(filename As String, data As String)
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Binary Access Write As #f
        Put #f, , data
    Close #f 
End Sub
```