# Python unpack equivalent in vba

Tags: python, vba, unpack

Does anyone know the equivalent of the Python unpack function in vba.  Ultimately, trying to read a file as binary, loading the data into a Byte array then converting certain portions of the byte array into floating point numbers using little endian ordering.  I can do this in Python, but would prefer to use vba for other reasons.

Comment: You are looking for `Open "FileName" For Binary Access Write As #1` Here is a small sample to load into an Array. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49522684/7868938

Comment: @RicardoA, I can already perform the Open "xxx" For Binary As.  I can actually place every byte entry into a cell in excel, but these come out as ASCI formatted values.