# How can I extract the "Compression" attribute from a jpeg file in Windows 10 using VBA (or PowerShell)?

Tags: vba, powershell, file, attributes, jpeg

I'm trying to extract the Compression attribute from several thousand jpeg files.

[image]

How can I do this with either Excel VBA or PowerShell (or some other method)?

Some users haven't used the correct technique to convert tiff or png files to jpegs. They just edited the file extension directly in Explorer instead of using an app like Photoshop to properly change the file format. This is causing trouble in a downstream process.

After checking a few files, the problematic ones have 'Uncompressed' in that field...and I want to isolate these so they can be corrected.

Note that [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890/using-vba-to-get-extended-file-attributes) does not provide the solution I need. The Compression attribute is not in the list of 308 attributes output by that method.

Comment: How about the ImageMagick command-line tool (`-identify` parameter, possibly)?

Comment: Thanks Bill...I'd need to go through our IT group to get that software installed (admin creds required). Could you run a test on your end for POC. If you can pull the data from the Compression field with ImageMagick, then I'll ask them to install it for me.

Comment: https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html has a listing of byte signatures for many common file types.  You can test the files against each of the ones you're interested in to make sure the type matches the extension.    Reading bytes from a file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660312/how-can-i-read-a-binary-file-using-vba

Comment: "Could you run a test on your end" - sorry, I don't have time to do that for you. I would recommend installing on a personal computer and then user that to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my earlier comment - if your aim is really to id the *actual* file type (vs. relying on the file extension)

```
Sub Tester()

    Const fldr As String = "C:\Temp\pics\"
    
    Debug.Print FileTypeId(fldr & "photo.jpg")
    Debug.Print FileTypeId(fldr & "unlock.gif")
    Debug.Print FileTypeId(fldr & "unlock2.png")
    Debug.Print FileTypeId(fldr & "sample.tiff")

End Sub


Function FileTypeId(fPath As String) As String

    Dim bytes() As Byte, ff As Integer, i As Long
    
    'read the file into an array of bytes
    ff = FreeFile
    Open fPath For Binary Access Read As ff
    ReDim bytes(0 To LOF(ff) - 1) 'maybe don't need to read more than the first 10 bytes or so...
    Get ff, , bytes
    Close ff

    'Does the file match any of our "known" types?
    '  File signatures are taken from:
    '  https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html
    Select Case True
        Case ByteMatch(bytes, Array(&HFF, &HD8))
            FileTypeId = "JPEG"
        Case ByteMatch(bytes, Array(&H47, &H49, &H46, &H38, &H37, &H61)), _
             ByteMatch(bytes, Array(&H47, &H49, &H46, &H38, &H39, &H61))
             FileTypeId = "GIF"
        Case ByteMatch(bytes, Array(&H89, &H50, &H4E, &H47, &HD, &HA, &H1A, &HA))
            FileTypeId = "PNG"
        Case ByteMatch(bytes, Array(&H49, &H49, &H2A, &H0))
            FileTypeId = "TIFF"
        Case Else
            FileTypeId = "unknown"
    End Select
    
'    Debug.Print fPath
'    Debug.Print FileTypeId
'    For i = LBound(bytes) To 6
'        Debug.Print Hex(bytes(i))
'    Next i
End Function

'do the first elements in `bytes` match `sig` ? 
Function ByteMatch(bytes, sig) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(sig) To UBound(sig)
        If bytes(i) <> sig(i) Then
           ByteMatch = False
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    ByteMatch = True
End Function
```

Comment: A quick test revealed that this is likely going to work. The "Uncompressed" (improperly converted "JPEG") test file came back as "TIFF"...so now I'll integrate into a FSO routine to scan the entire folder. Will get back with details soon.

Comment: You may want to check for other image formats, so you can add those from the page linked above.

Comment: This worked really well, thanks Tim. I ended up just copying all of the paths into a worksheet and then looping through the list to capture each file type.  Turns out there were six tiffs and one png that were improperly converted (and two corrupt files that threw errors).

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes it may be sufficient to distinguish mangled files containing some other sort of image format from JPEGs by looking for the SOI tag that should be at the start of a genuine classical JPEG file namely 0xffd8. Occurrence of "JFIF" as text a few bytes in is also a pretty good indication of a JPEG (but no guarantee). MS Bitmap files mostly begin with "BM" but there other [possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). And PNG starts 0x89504E47 which includes the letters PNG. ISTR GIF files start with "GIF". Finally TIFF will begin with either "II" or "MM". Then set the file extension back to being consistent with the file contents and you should be OK to go. This should be simple enough open the file read the first word to check what you actually have in the file data (may need additional heuristics for other esoteric image formats).

You could also try re-educating your users with a baseball bat.

Simplest common tool to check this out is save a small image in each format in a temp directory and then use more to see the first block. Obviously in VBA you would open the file for binary read and get the first two bytes. I'm not sure how well stackOverflow reacts to top bit set characters so this sample output might not behave as intended.

```
C:\temp>more test.bmp
BM6°%

C:\temp>more test.gif
GIF89aÇð¸


C:\temp>more test.jpg
 Ï Ó
JFIF

C:\temp>more test.png
ëPNG


C:\temp>more test.tif
II*
```

It didn't occur to me that you wouldn't have a hexadecimal editor to hand. This is minimal VBA code to check and display the first two bytes of any file.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim i As Integer
  Debug.Print "Graphics File Headers"
  testfile ("C:\temp\test.jpg")
  testfile ("C:\temp\test.png")
  testfile ("C:\temp\test.gif")
  testfile ("C:\temp\test.tif")
End Sub

Sub testfile(fname As String)
  Dim tag1 As Byte, tag2 As Byte
  Open fname For Binary Access Read As 1
  Get #1, , tag1
  Get #1, , tag2
  Debug.Print fname, Hex(tag1), Hex(tag2), Chr(tag1) & Chr(tag2)
  Close #1
End Sub

Output:
Graphics File Headers
C:\temp\test.jpg            FF            D8            ÿØ
C:\temp\test.png            89            50            ‰P
C:\temp\test.gif            47            49            GI
C:\temp\test.tif            49            49            II
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I can't figure out how to view the SOI tag (0xffd8), but I do see 'JFIF' a few characters into the first line of a valid jpg dragged into Notepad. So that's progress. I did look around for how to extract the true SOI tag with no luck, so please recommend a method for that when you get a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @MBB70 Any hex editor or just read the first four bytes of the file into a string and then classify it according to the bytes or characters that you see there. fileAttributes is as you have found out incredibly simple minded and cannot be trusted. It is a bit limp in this day and age that so many applications cannot work out for themselves what image format a file is encoded with and still rely blindly on the file extension.

Comment: I tried to use Notepad++ as a hex editor but it seems my copy is not set up properly to do this...will need to get with IT to address that. For the record, this is what I see in Notepad++ for my real jpeg (ÿØÿà JFIF  H H  ÿá)....and this is what I see in the 'fake' one (II*      )....JFIF is only in the real one.

Comment: You should be able to grab the first 4 bytes with `Get-Content` like so: `Get-Content -TotalCount 4 c:\test.jpg`. Running it on my test compressed jpg returned `ÿØÿÛC`. It returned 2 lines from my uncompressed test image, so I forced it to only return JFIF like so: `Get-Content -TotalCount 4 c:\test.jpg | findstr "JFIF"`. If simply checking if a file has a specific string in it helps, then this should get you started. You can output in hex as well: `Get-Content -TotalCount 4 c:\test.jpg |format-hex | findstr "JFIF"`

Comment: @MBBB70 I've shown a sample obtained by the simple more command line tool in DOS. Obviously you can't see the hexadecimal values but you should be able to write a simple VBA program to read the first two bytes of each file and classify it based on that.

Comment: @MBB70 I've added sample VBA code to probe the first two bytes of a file to my answer with sample results on toy image files of each common type - hope that helps. The so called "properties" of image files on WIndows are extremely misleading the only time that Paint sets Compression is when the save format is TIF!

Answer (score 1):

A pragmatic solution is to use the powerful [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) CLI, which can be installed at a user level (no admin credentials required).

Here's a **PowerShell solution** with unattended on-demand installation via `winget.exe`:

```bash
# Install ExifTool.exe on demand
if (-not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore ExifTool.exe)) {
  Write-Verbose 'Installing OliverBetz.ExifTool on demand...'
  winget install OliverBetz.ExifTool --silent >$null
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw }
  Write-Verbose 'Refreshing $env:PATH...'
  $env:PATH = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine'),
              [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -join ';'
}

# Get the compression info from the specified image files in the current dir.
# as JSON, and parse the output into objects via Convert-FromJson
$imageCompressionInfo = 
  exiftool -j -Compression *.png *.bmp *.jpg *.tiff |
  ConvertFrom-Json

# Output only those that are uncompressed
$imageCompressionInfo | Where-Object Compression -eq None
```

Comment: This looks promising...and I was excited to try it...but installing winget itself will require admin credentials. I'm getting the 'The term ‘winget’ is not recognized...' error on the winget install line. If it comes to a point where I have no other options, I'll ask them to install it so I can try this. Thanks for your input.

Comment: My pleasure, @MBB70. You _may_ be able to install `winget.exe` even without admin rights - for your user account only -  using the approach shown [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/#install-winget-on-windows-sandbox). (The instructions pertain to the Windows Sandbox, but should equally work on regular machines).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with API `GetFileAttributes`.

```vb
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetFileAttributes Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetFileAttributesA" (ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
#End If
Private Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED As Long = &H800
Sub GetCompressionStatus()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileAttributes As Long
    filePath = "d:\temp\my.jpg"
    fileAttributes = GetFileAttributes(filePath)
    Debug.Print fileAttributes ' for debug
    If (fileAttributes And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED Then
        MsgBox "COMPRESSED"
    Else
        MsgBox "NO COMPRESSED"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @taller...I just tested that code and unfortunately the results are the same for every file. The ones that have no data in the Compression field are also coming back as 'NOT COMPRESSED.'

Comment: I guess the Exif may be different. Please add `Debug.Print fileAttributes` to check the difference for your images. Then you can revise the `If` statement.

Comment: To clarify, the problematic files have 'Uncompressed' in the Compression field and the files that aren't causing trouble have no data in the Compression field. I need a routine that isolates the files that have Uncompressed in that field.

Comment: I don't have `files have 'Uncompressed' in the Compression field`. You need to find out the return value of `fileAttributes`.

Comment: I decided to see what MS Paint puts into toy files of each main image format it handles. It isn't at all encouraging. I drew a squiggle and saved it. Most fields are blank in the extended info (which is absent from BMP, PNG & GIF). JPG has all the fields but nothing in most of them and TIF is the only one which has Compression=LZW. The least error prone method by far is to examine the first two bytes of the file!

Comment: Software may populate EXIF in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method in my opinion would be via WMIC, which is native to windows and usable via CMD and Powershell. Here's an example of the command and its output:

```
wmic datafile where "name='C:\\test.jpg'"
    AccessMask  Archive  Caption      Compressed  CompressionMethod  CreationClassName  CreationDate               CSCreationClassName   CSName           Description  Drive  EightDotThreeFileName  Encrypted  EncryptionMethod  Extension  FileName  FileSize  FileType    FSCreationClassName  FSName  Hidden  InstallDate                InUseCount  LastAccessed               LastModified               Manufacturer  Name         Path  Readable  Status  System  Version  Writeable
1507775     TRUE     C:\test.jpg  FALSE                          CIM_LogicalFile    20231128113827.761885-480  Win32_ComputerSystem  DESKTOP-XXXXXXX  C:\test.jpg  c:     c:\test.jpg            FALSE                        jpg        test      5440375   JPEG Image  Win32_FileSystem     NTFS    FALSE   20231128113827.761885-480              20231128114415.151472-480  20231108204657.602147-480                C:\test.jpg  \     TRUE      OK      FALSE            TRUE
```

This output can be tweaked, summarized or isolated as well, like so:

```
PS C:\> wmic datafile where "name='C:\\test.jpg'" list brief
Compressed  Encrypted  FileSize  Hidden  Name         Readable  System  Version  Writeable
FALSE       FALSE      5440375   FALSE   C:\test.jpg  TRUE      FALSE            TRUE
```

See more in the wmic help :)

```
wmic /?
```

EDIT:
Figured I'd add exact value return, since you're only looking for compression state:

```
wmic datafile where "name='C:\\test.jpg'" get Compressed
```

Returns:

```
Compressed
FALSE
```

You can parse this within your script however you like.

Comment: Thank you for your response...unfortunately I think IT has our system locked down where we can't use this tool. I tried several times in both PowerShell and cmd with the same results...Invalid Query. Also, when I enter 'wmic /?' I get a list of all the commands, but up at the top it says 'WMIC is deprecated.' Maybe they've disabled the tool.

Comment: wmic datafile where "name='\\bethyl-fs1\ProductDatabase\AllImages\Phospho-MEK1-T286-Antibody-Ms-IHC-1-Bethyl-Laboratories-A303-610A-1.jpg'"

Comment: Do you see any problems in that line? Note that I also moved the file from our server to my local C drive and got the same result.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I'm pretty sure you need to double-slash every backslash, not just the first.
Also, I was unaware that wmic was getting depricated. Unfortunate, its a great tool.
Its apparently getting replace with WMI, which doesn't have capability to dig into file attributes, but I found something that might work if you aren't going with wmic. This command returns 0 for me when I run it against my test image (uncompressed) but I can't find a COMPRESSED to test against.
`(Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\test.jpg).attributes -band [io.fileattributes]::Compressed`

Comment: @STR4NG3R JPEG is a lossy DCT based compression method using Huffman encoding.  It is **impossible** to have an uncompressed one by definition! Bytewise file entropy of a decent sized JPEG is typically around 250/255 equivalent histogram states used S~5.5 out of a theoretical maximum of ln(256) = 5.545177444 for perfect compression.

Comment: @MartinBrown my test image is only JPG by name. Its an output of fswebcam (linux) that I'm pretty sure defaults to PNG format, and defaults to 0 (actually -1) compression. So my test.jpg is actually test.png masquerading, or slumming it if you prefer :) That said, I could be wrong an any/all counts. I'm no expert by any means. Also, given your response, I tested the Get-ItemProperty query against a true jpg from some website, and it also returned 0, so that suggestion likely won't do the trick. Thanks for the bit of knowledge.

Comment: Update: I got wmic to work, but I had to make a copy of the file on my local drive first (escaping all the backslashes in the server path above didn't work...probably because IT has prevented ops like these on the server). Unfortunately, I'm getting Compressed = False for both files I tested...so I don't think this corresponds to the Compression field in the Image section of the file properties. I'll try the other method you suggested.

Comment: The Get-ItemProperty method produced '0' for both files...so same issue there I think.

Comment: Highly unfortunate, I was confident the WMIC method would work for you. Sorry to waste your time, but at least I learned something today, thanks to Martin. I'll leave my answer up, as I expect it will function as needed for others who find their way to this question, as I suspect its highly dependent on how the file metadata was written. Martin's hex option (manually reading first 4 bytes) might be your only saving grace at this point.

Comment: @STR4NG3R It is also impossible to find an uncompressed PNG in the wild. Normally they have an even higher byte entropy than JPEGs since it works very hard to compress losslessly. I think the most reliable way is simply to test the file header for the signature bytes of each format(s) you want to handle. It is appalling that Windows metadata for some well known highly compressed image formats returns the answer "uncompressed" :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell answer. Remember that `WMI` is not available in PowerShell Core. Use CIM.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DataFile -Filter "Name='C:\\Test.jpg'").Compressed
```

Is there a separate filesystem compression and image compression?

Here is code that produces a list of shell properties. I do not see anything about compression except for "video compression," and I am not sure that is what you want.

```
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($Env:USERPROFILE)
(1..325) | %{ '{0}, {1}' -f ($_,$shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($null, $_)) }
```

Comment: Good question @lit...I was thinking the same. The Compression I'm after is the one in the Image section of the file properties...and I think the routines we're discussing here might be for filesystem compression.

Comment: Both of my files (one with 'Uncompressed' in the Compression field in the image section of the file properties and the other with nothing there) come back with False using the Get-CimInstance method...so I'm surmising that this is also a filesystem method.